# Slot machine game using python

Tags: python, pygame

I made a 3 reel slot machine using the pygame library in Python. This is what I have so far.
I want to improve it to make it work for a 3x5 slot machine with multiple paylines, right now it is a 1x3 slot machine.
I also want to improve on my programming skills as I am still fairly new to programming and have only been doing it for about a year. If anyone has any recommendations on how to make this code cleaner or more efficient, let me know.
nums.json contains this list of numbers. I made this list of numbers so some icons have more weight than others, hence why some give the player more money.
[
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
2,
2
]

This is the slotmachine class file.

```
import random

import json

f = open("nums.json")
nums = json.load(f)

class SlotMachine:
    def __init__(self, windict):
        self.windict = windict
        self.output = ""

    def play(self):
        num = random.choice(nums)
        self.output += str(num)
        return num

    def checkwin(self):
        if self.output in self.windict:
            win = str(self.windict[self.output] * 100)
            self.output = ""
            return win
        else:
            loss = "0"
            self.output = ""
            return loss
```

This is the main Python file.

```
import pygame

from slotmachine import SlotMachine

import time

pygame.init()
eagles = "The Best of My Love - On the Border (front).jpg"
beatles = "Abbey Road (front).jpg"
pink = "Wish you were here (front).jpg"
(width, height) = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ryan's Slot Machine")
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 128)
screen.fill(white)
bg = pygame.image.load("border.png")
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
picdict = {0: eagles, 1: beatles, 2: pink}
positions = ((200, 275), (350, 275), (497, 275))
slot = SlotMachine({"000": 1, "111": 2, "222": 5})
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 25)


def icon_to_screen(x, y, path):
    icon = pygame.image.load(path)
    small_icon = pygame.transform.scale(icon, (100,50))
    screen.blit(small_icon, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    

def main():
    play = True
    while play:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    screen.fill(white)
                    bg = pygame.image.load("border.png")
                    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    for position in positions:
                        i = slot.play()
                        icon_to_screen(position[0], position[1], picdict[i])
                        time.sleep(.5)
                    text = font.render(slot.checkwin(), True, green, blue)
                    screen.blit(text, (670,36))
                    pygame.display.update()

              
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`nums.json` should have a better name like `weights.json`, and should only contain three numbers: the weights of each slot outcome, as in

```json
 [ 10, 5, 2 ]
```

When you open this file, do so with a context manager.

`picdict` shouldn't be a dictionary: you have a simple integer index, so just make it a tuple.

Don't call `random.choice`; call [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) passing your weights.

Don't make `output` stringly-typed. Build it up as a tuple of integers. Similarly, `checkwin` (which should be named `check_win`) should return an integer and not a string.

The logic in `check_win` can be simplified by unconditionally calling `get` on `windict` with a default of `0` for no winnings. Only reset `output` once.

Some of the simple constants like your colours can stay as capitalised constants in the global namespace. The rest of the global code should move into a function. One easy way to achieve this is to move the global code into the `__init__` of a class.

`play` needs to go away, and you should just use a `while True`.

When you check `KEYDOWN` you should simultaneously check the key code after an `and`.

Add a constant for things like the antialias parameter to `render()`.

### Suggested

Only partially tested since I don't have your images:

```py
import json
import random
import pygame
import time

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 128)
ANTIALIAS = True

with open("nums.json") as f:
    WEIGHTS = json.load(f)


class SlotMachine:
    def __init__(self, win_dict: dict[tuple[int, ...], int]):
        self.win_dict = win_dict
        self.output: tuple[int, ...] = ()

    def play(self) -> int:
        num, = random.choices(population=range(3), weights=WEIGHTS)
        self.output += num,
        return num

    def check_win(self) -> int:
        winnings = self.win_dict.get(self.output, 0)
        self.output = ()
        return 100 * winnings


class Game:
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
    POSITIONS = (200, 275), (350, 275), (497, 275)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Ryan's Slot Machine")

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)

        self.bg = pygame.image.load("border.png")
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()

        self.slot_pictures = (
            "The Best of My Love - On the Border (front).jpg",
            "Abbey Road (front).jpg",
            "Wish you were here (front).jpg",
        )
        self.machine = SlotMachine({(0, 0, 0): 1, (1, 1, 1): 2, (2, 2, 2): 5})
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 25)

    def icon_to_screen(self, x: int, y: int, path: str) -> None:
        icon = pygame.image.load(path)
        small_icon = pygame.transform.scale(icon, (100, 50))
        self.screen.blit(small_icon, (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    self.screen.fill(WHITE)
                    self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
                    pygame.display.update()

                    for x, y in self.POSITIONS:
                        i = self.machine.play()
                        self.icon_to_screen(x, y, self.slot_pictures[i])
                        time.sleep(.5)

                    winning_string = str(self.machine.check_win())
                    foreground = GREEN
                    background = BLUE
                    text = self.font.render(winning_string, ANTIALIAS, foreground, background)
                    self.screen.blit(text, (670, 36))
                    pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().run()
```

You can further simplify by not keeping an `output` and not mutating the slot machine at all; just returning three reels at once; and including the factor of 100 in your winnings dictionary:

```py
import json
import random
import pygame
import time

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 128)
ANTIALIAS = True


class SlotMachine:
    def __init__(self, win_dict: dict[tuple[int, ...], int]):
        with open("weights.json") as f:
            self.weights = json.load(f)
        self.win_dict = win_dict

    def play(self) -> list[int]:  # reel positions
        return random.choices(population=range(3), weights=self.weights, k=3)

    def check_win(self, reels: list[int]) -> int:
        return self.win_dict.get(tuple(reels), 0)


class Game:
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
    POSITIONS = (200, 275), (350, 275), (497, 275)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Ryan's Slot Machine")

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)

        self.bg = pygame.image.load("border.png")
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()

        self.slot_pictures = (
            "The Best of My Love - On the Border (front).jpg",
            "Abbey Road (front).jpg",
            "Wish you were here (front).jpg",
        )
        self.machine = SlotMachine({
            (0, 0, 0): 100,
            (1, 1, 1): 200,
            (2, 2, 2): 500,
        })
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 25)

    def icon_to_screen(self, x: int, y: int, path: str) -> None:
        icon = pygame.image.load(path)
        small_icon = pygame.transform.scale(icon, (100, 50))
        self.screen.blit(small_icon, (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    self.screen.fill(WHITE)
                    self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
                    pygame.display.update()

                    reels = self.machine.play()
                    for (x, y), reel in zip(self.POSITIONS, reels):
                        self.icon_to_screen(x, y, self.slot_pictures[reel])
                        time.sleep(.5)

                    winning_string = str(self.machine.check_win(reels))
                    foreground = GREEN
                    background = BLUE
                    text = self.font.render(winning_string, ANTIALIAS, foreground, background)
                    self.screen.blit(text, (670, 36))
                    pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().run()
```